# Invalid routes are not caught by @app.errorhandler(Exception) in flask

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, flask

The below code catches `Not Found` exceptions:

```
@app.errorhandler(404) 
def default_handler(e):
    return 'not-found', 404
```

The problem is that when I use general purpose `errorhandler` it fails to catch `404` errors:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def default_handler(e):
    return 'server-error', 500
```

For the time being I use to error handler one for `404` and another for other errors. Why `Not Found` exceptions are not caught by the second one? Is there a way to use one `errorhandler`?

**EDIT:**
routes are handles by both `flask-restful` and `@app.route()`. `flask-restful` is used for handling resources and `@app.route()` for those who are not applicable to resources.

Comment: Are you using flask-restful?

Comment: @doru yes its the module I use to handle resource routes. Of course beside it I have other routes that doesn't use flask-restful, it uses `@app.route()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are only passing the `app` object of Flask to the `Api` constructor.

But, you can add another argument in the Constructor called `catch_all_404s` which takes a `bool`.

[From here](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#id1):

```
api = Api(app, catch_all_404s=True)
```

This should let a `404` error route to your `handle_error()` method.

Even after doing this, if it doesn't handle the errors your way, you could subclass the Api. [From here](http://www.wiredmonk.me/error-handling-and-logging-in-flask-restful.html):

```
class MyApi(Api):
    def handle_error(self, e):
        """ Overrides the handle_error() method of the Api and adds custom error handling
        :param e: error object
        """
        code = getattr(e, 'code', 500)  # Gets code or defaults to 500
        if code == 404:
            return self.make_response({
                'message': 'not-found',
                'code': 404
            }, 404)
    return super(MyApi, self).handle_error(e)  # handle others the default way
```

And then after doing that, you could initialize your `api` object using the `MyApi` object instead of the `Api` object.

Like this,

```
api = MyApi(app, catch_all_404s=True)
```

Let me know if this works. This is one of my first Answers on Stack Overflow.